# log4cpp: two problems about SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am working on a cpp project under Linux and I want to build a log system to write down some important information into a file. So I use this libraty: [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/#simpleexample)

Here is my code about log4cpp:

```
// class Log head file
class Log
{
public:
    explicit Log(const char * infoCategory = nullptr, const string & pattern = string("%d: %p %c %x: %m%n"), const char * filename = "log")
    : category(infoCategory == nullptr ? Category::getRoot() : Category::getRoot().getInstance(infoCategory))
    {
        logFile.open(filename, ios::app);
        osAppender = new OstreamAppender("osAppender", &logFile);
        patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout->setConversionPattern(pattern);
        osAppender->setLayout(patternLayout);
        category.addAppender(osAppender);
        logFile.seekp(0, ios::end);
        size = logFile.tellp();
    }
    ~Log()
    {
        category.shutdown();
        logFile.close();
        // Do NOT delete osAppender and patternLayout
    }
    void info(const string & info)
    {
        category.info(info);
    }
private:
    ofstream logFile;
    streampos size;
    Category & category;
    OstreamAppender * osAppender;
    PatternLayout * patternLayout;
};
```

Now, I can use `Log` to write down something. For example, there is a class Agent like this:

```
#include "Log.h"
class Agent
{
public:
    ~Agent()
    {
        terminate();
    }
    void initialize()
    {
        log.info(" initialized.");
    }
    void terminate()
    {
        log.info(" terminated.");
    }
    static Agent & getInstance()
    {
        static Agent agent;
        return agent;
    }
    Agent()
    {
    }
private:
    Log log;
};
```

the function `getInstance` is to generate the "Singleton". Its constructor is private so we have to call `getInstance` to generate an object. As this object is static, so it can be initialize ONLY ONE time.
Now in the `main`, I write this:

```
int main()
{
    Agent & agent = Agent::getInstance();
    agent.initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I run it, the project will stop in the function `Log::info` and I will get this error:`Signal received: SIGSEGV(Segmentation fault)`
**To my surprise, if I delete `log.info("terminated.");` or delete `log.info("initialized");` or I move two `info` into the function `initialize` or `terminate`, the error will disappear.

Or, if I initialize a normal `Agent` in the function `main`, I means I don't use `getInstance`, instead, I do this: `Agent agent;`, the error will disappear too.

Or, if I new an `Agent` in the function `getInstance`, instead of using `static`, the error will disappear too.**

This is my first question.

My second question is here:
Please note that there is a comment in the destructor of `Log`:
`// do NOT delete osAppender and patternLayout`

I put such a comment because I think both of them are pointers which come from `new`, so I could and should delete them. But if I delete one of them or both of them, I will get the same error:
`Signal received:SIGSEGV`.

Comment: if someone works under Linux too, can you install the log4cpp and do a test for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I got this problem because `log` and `agent` here are all static.
It means that both of them will be free **after** `return 0;` in the function `main`, and we can't decide the order of free.
In this case, obviously before the virtual function of `agent` is called, the `log` has been free so when I called `terminate()` in the virtual function, there would be an error.